# Does jboss handle managed Entity Manager concurrency issues for me?

Tags: jakarta-ee, concurrency, jboss, jta

It seems that the Entity Manager instance jboss manages and provides is a proxy to the actual implementation bound to a persistence context.

This actual implementation gathers the isolation provided by JTA transactions (per transaction contexts).

That makes me think I don't need to worry about concurrency issues when dealing with the proxy instance.

Maybe I can even cache this proxy instance if I decide to bring it from JNDI lookups instead of container injection?

Is that reasonable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The container is responsible for scanning for `@PersistenceContext` annotations and injection of `EntityManagers`. It **can** proxy the instances of `EntityManager`.

In EJB, where the container is responsible for dependency injection, you can be sure that you're thread-safe. The persistence context will be shared between multiple components within the same transaction.

However, if you inject this `EntityManager` using `@PersistenceContext` in Servlets environment (where the concurrency is a concern), you're **not** thread-safe. You should use `@PersistenceUnit` instead. You can refer to this part of the [JBoss 7 JPA Reference Guide](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/JPA+Reference+Guide):

> Keep in mind that the entity manager is not expected to be thread safe
>   **(don't inject it into a servlet class variable which is visible to
>   multiple threads)**.

Some time ago I've summed up what I know about Persistence Context sharing between JTA transactions and proxying of `EntityManagers` by the container and published it [here](http://piotrnowicki.com/2011/11/am-i-in-the-same-transaction-am-i-using-the-same-persistencecontext/). I hope you'll find it useful.