# How JPA transactions works

Tags: hibernate, jpa, transactions, jpa-2.0

Following code gets executed whenever I want to persist any entity. Things seems to be working fine but I fail to understand how it works !

```
EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
EntityTransaction userTransaction = em.getTransaction();
userTransaction.begin();
em.persist( ent );
userTransaction.commit();
```

The EntityManager above is a single instance shared by whole application. After starting the transaction; I just say em.persist(entity).. How does hibernate know it belongs to which transaction !

Suppose there are 10 concurrent users on my application and all 10 threads executing above code. So 10 independent transactions  are getting created and committed. But all 10 different entities I am not associating them with their respective transactions; so how is JPA able to work it out !

Based on answers; we have below;  are we saying that we should have an EntityManager instance per thread ? Will that not be a kill on the server ! Should we be pooling these instances ? Will it not be equal to again implementing sort of Connection Pooling ?

Comment: What do you mean "which transaction"? An EM has a single (local) Transaction at any time; it doesn't have multiple. Sharing a single EM across multiple threads is a recipe for problems, since it is not guaranteed to be thread-safe.

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/hem/en-US/html/transactions.html  A EntityManagerFactory is an expensive-to-create, threadsafe object intended to be shared by all application threads. It is created once, usually on application startup. An EntityManager is an inexpensive, non-threadsafe object that should be used once, for a single business process, a single unit of work, and then discarded

Comment: On further reading; what I understand is that creation of EntityManager is lightweight but still not very light weight that for each small DB operation we create it. Suggested solution is to create EM per request. So, which looks like it should be at ThreadLocal level.

Comment: I understand EntityManager is not threadsafe for which we should create new objects. But do we need to create new EntityManagers for select query too ( for which we dont start any transaction ) .. Will that not be overkill ?

Comment: An EntityManager needs to be created when you need an EntityManager operation, and if you need a Query then how else do you get the Query?

Comment: I understand we need EntityManager. We know EntityManager is not thread safe so for sure we need new instance whenever we are doing DDL operation and starts  a transaction.  But do we need new instance when we need select query and we do not do transaction.begin()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It works because you are lucky enough. Lucky enough means that commit and begin are called in right order - accidentally.

You do use single instance of entity manager from multiple threads. That is wrong thing to do, because it is not guaranteed to be thread safe. Access to resource level transaction via EntityTransaction is bound to entity manager instance, not to the thread.

So result is that you are sharing same EntityTransaction and using it luckily serially for multiple transactions. Using it serially to strart and end multiple transaction is fine, but using it from many threads is not.

In hibernate (4.1.4) reference is stored to tx instance  field in AbstractEntityManageImpl class, but that is just implementation detail.

Comment: are we saying that we should have an EntityManager instance per thread ? Will that not be a kill on the server ! Should we be pooling these instances ? Will it not be equal to again implementing sort of Connection Pooling ?

Comment: EntityManager is quite light object to create, EntityManagerFactory is heavy weight. No reason to start pool entity managers.

Comment: I understand EntityManager is not threadsafe for which we should create new objects. But do we need to create new EntityManagers for select query too ( for which we dont start any transaction ) .. Will that not be overkill ?

Comment: It does not make difference is it used for SELECT, UPDATE, or INSERT. One instance can be used for multiple queries/operations, but not simultaneously.

Answer (score 7):

It's using [ThreadLocal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) variables for the Transaction.

See also the documentation for [UserTransaction](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/transaction/UserTransaction.html):

> begin()
>   Create a new transaction and associate it with the current thread.

You should not share the EntityManager though since it is not guaranteed to be thread-safe.

However if you are injecting it in an EJB, you don't have to worry about thread-safety: http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/is_in_an_ejb_injected

If you are using Spring to inject it, you'll get a thread-safe proxy: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.1.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-jpa-straight

> Although EntityManagerFactory instances are thread-safe, EntityManager instances are not. The injected JPA EntityManager behaves like an EntityManager fetched from an application server's JNDI environment, as defined by the JPA specification. It delegates all calls to the current transactional EntityManager, if any; otherwise, it falls back to a newly created EntityManager per operation, in effect making its usage thread-safe.

Comment: That is not true at least for fresh implementations of Hibernate. Why would it use ThreadLocal in object which is ment to be used from single thread only?

Comment: It seems to depend on where you use it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8603478/does-jboss-handle-managed-entity-manager-concurrency-issues-for-me

Comment: No, injection does not itself make single instance of entity manager thread safe. Instead serialized access to ejb provider by container guarantees that it is not used simultaneously from multiple threads. You can also use jndi lookup instead of injection and guarantee thread safety by ejb contract.

Comment: Injection can do this by injecting a proxy that delegates to a thread specific instance. Spring does this: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.1.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-jpa-straight

Comment: Of course, that is right. I just didn't saw any reason to assume that Spring components are used in this case.

Answer (score 2):

The transaction is associated with the current thread somehow, using a ThreadLocal variable.

Comment: So is above design flawless or not ! I am still confused !

Comment: It all depends on how you get an instance of EntityManager. If it's injected in EJBs or in Spring beans (as explained in the Spring documentation), the EntityManager is in fact a proxy to the actual EntityManager implementation. If not, see Mikko Maunu's answer.

Comment: I understand EntityManager is not threadsafe for which we should create new objects. But do we need to create new EntityManagers for select query too ( for which we dont start any transaction ) .. Will that not be overkill ?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you understand how [JTA](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/jta/index.html) works regardless of Hibernate - it's quite important for your to understand 
In addition, read about container-managed transactions and bean managed transactions. 
If you're working in a container-managed transaction, you can specify for the bean you're injecting the EntityManager to what is the transaction scope - 
for example - if the scope is REQUIRED, it means that if another bean calls this bean, and not in context of transaction, a new transaction will be open. If a transaction already exists, then you will use the same transaction. It is important to understand this, as transactions are an expensive resource in your system. 
A transaction object is associated with ThreadLocal, however, another thread may resume a suspended transaction, depends on the implementation of your TransactionManager (I am talking about [JBossTransactionManager](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/jboss4guide/r4/html/ch4.chapt.html))

Comment: He's using local transactions here, as shown by the call to em.getTransaction(). And in that case there is only 1 transaction per EM, and his design is flawed.