# SQL returning wrong data

Tags: java, sql, mariadb

for some reason my SQL connection seems to be returning a completely invalid response. Somehow between one call and the next (after a brief period of time, about a second) it returns an entirely different value. I should note that I have other rows set up the exact same way that do not have this problem.

I should note that I'm using apache dbcp2 for the SQL datasource which is where the getConnection() is calling. I should note that everything else works just fine but not this for some reason.

Hope I included enough information. I'm not asking for you to do the work for me, I just have no idea what the issue could be here.

```
//First call
//Note Global.TOKEN_TTL is a constant value of 300000
System.out.println((System.currentTimeMillis() + Global.TOKEN_TTL));
Start.getSQLConnection().setTTL(userID, (System.currentTimeMillis() + Global.TOKEN_TTL));
System.out.println(Start.getSQLConnection().getTTL(userID));
//Second Call
System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
System.out.println(Start.getSQLConnection().getTTL(userID));


Output
----Call one
System call: 1529456964416
DB call:     1529456964416
DB Actual:   1529456964416
----Call two
System call: 1529456665144
DB call:     4294967295
DB Actual:   1529456964416
```

*The database is set up using MariaDB. The row is a signed BIGINT with a length of 20.*

**Retrieval**

Code below is in order of called first to last:

First call:

```
getLong("adbname", "TTL", "SELECT TTL FROM atablename WHERE ID=?;", userID);
```

Second call:

```
public long getLong(String database, String tag, String sql, Object... parameters) throws SQLException {
    return (long) getObject(database, sql, tag, parameters);
}
```

Third call:

```
public Object getObject(String database, String sql, String tag, Object... parameters) throws SQLException {
    Connection conn = getConnection(database);
    conn.setAutoCommit(false);
    PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    assert parameters != null && parameters.length > 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < parameters.length; i++) {
        stmt.setObject(i + 1, parameters[i]);
    }
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
    if (!rs.next())
        return null;

    Object o = rs.getObject(tag);
    conn.commit();

    if (rs != null)
        rs.close();
    if (stmt != null)
        stmt.close();
    if (conn != null)
        conn.close();

    return o;
}
```

**Setting**

```
public boolean setTTL(long userID, long TTL) throws SQLException {
    return executeUpdate("adbname", "UPDATE atablename SET TTL=? WHERE ID=?;", TTL, userID);
}
//The actual work
public boolean executeUpdate(String database, String sql, Object... parameters) throws SQLException {
    Connection conn = getConnection(database);
    conn.setAutoCommit(false);
    PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    for (int i = 0; i < parameters.length; i++) {
        stmt.setObject(i + 1, parameters[i]);
    }
    boolean result = stmt.executeUpdate() > 0;
    conn.commit();

    if (stmt != null)
        stmt.close();
    if (conn != null)
        conn.close();

    return result;
}
```

Comment: In `getObject` and `executeUpdate` you should wrap your opening anf closing into a `try-with=resource` so that if a exception happens it will be guaranteed to close.  Also where are you using any `transactions`?

Comment: Changed the closing, running "BEGIN;" and "COMMIT;" before and after the SQL statement respectively doesn't seem to make sense. If I'm using the transactions wrong do you have a decent guide for mariadb? From what I've managed to find that should do what I'm expecting.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11221072/how-jpa-transactions-works

Comment: Thanks for the link, it looks like in that case the issue is with concurrency and using the same connection. After modifying the code to create a new connection (and a new connection manager) for each thread I'm still left with the same result.

Comment: I gave you that link for illustration how to use transactions.  Unless you modify your question to show what you have done, it will be hard to help.

Comment: Didn't think I needed it for reads but had it just to make sure that wasn't causing any odd issues. Also there is no begin method for Connection. I've tried using conn.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED) to no different result. (Tried UNCOMITTED as well) I should note that the second read gives the same value even if the database hadn't been updated.

Comment: It is hard to understand from your code what is going wrong but, 1) why are you dealing in `Objects` rather than `longs`? 2) what is `Start.getSQLConnection()` doing and why is it necessary if within `executeUpdate` you are getting the connection via `Connection conn = getConnection(database);`  3) What exceptions are being thrown?  4) In this end I think this question is going to be Oops I forgot to tell you about ... and that is the problem  - try to make a bloody simple example

Answer (score 0):

I hate to admit this but @Scary Wombat was right. It ended up (not exactly) being one of those "oh I forgot to tell you" scenarios.

**The issue was a design flaw in the way that the user ID was being retrieved due to the fact that they weren't guaranteed to be unique (pretty serious flaw on my part). It was pulling data from another user.**

Thanks a ton for all the help, while it didn't directly solve the problem you gave me insight into a few things that I was doing wrong with SQL and storage in general. I'll make sure to remember this one, thanks again!

Comment: Glad to hear you fixed it

Answer (score 0):

The clue:  4294967295 = 2^32-1

Smells like you have a 32-bit build of some product, possibly even the OS.

Or you are using `INT UNSIGNED` when you need `BIGINT`.  You say "The row is a signed BIGINT with a length of 20" -- Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

And what is to keep `Object o = rs.getObject(tag);` from being limited to 32 bits?

Comment: It's a 64-bit product and OS, issue was that it was simply retrieving an invalid row. Thanks for the idea though, I'll keep that in mind!